# Pythonic way to write many try/except clauses?

Tags: python, excel

I am writing a script to write ~200 cells of somewhat unique data to an excel spreadsheet. My code is following this basic pattern:

```
try:
    sheet.cell(row=9, column=7).value = getData()
except:
    sheet.cell(row=9, column=7).value = 'NA'
```

Basically if there is an error then write some placeholder to the cell. I was wondering if there is a shorter, more pythonic way to write this than having 200 of these in sequence.

Comment: not if you cannot narrow down the exception you're getting. This try/except construct without anything else is bad design.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, you should have `getData` return NA instead of raising an exception

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I understand, exception could be occurred in getData() call. So you can wrap getData function as:

```
def get_data_or_default(default="NA"):
   try:
       return getData()
   except Exception:
       return default
```

And then just use:

```
sheet.cell(row=9, column=7).value = get_data_or_default()
```

Comment: I hope this is right. Because if not, the exception is coming from the assignment, meaning that `getData()` is capable of returning some value that cannot be written to an Excel file.

Comment: By the way, @erik-sn: replace `Exception` in the code above with the specific exception you expect to happen. Otherwise you will also catch other exceptions you should not, making debugging very hard.

Comment: @spectras: that's a matter of how good the documentation for `getData` is. Even some Python standard module functions don't actually tell you all the exceptions they can raise.

Comment: it's not optimal, but at least it wraps the "not optimal" code in one sole location. If it can be improved, it will take 5 minutes to do so. Good answer.

Comment: @SteveJessop> the point is **not** catching all the exceptions that can be raised. The point is catching the ones you expect and know you want to handle while letting others bubble up. It's a matter of taking 5 minutes to test what exceptions the errors you want to handle raise, even if documentation is incomplete. — here, catching some undefined data exception seems reasonable, while catching some I/O exception might not, and some memory error or `AssertionError` almost certainly isn't.

Comment: @spectras: if it really was only 5 minutes I'd submit a documentation patch and get on with it...

Comment: @SteveJessop> no python documentation tell all the exceptions they can raise. That's not the point. The point is telling which error condition you care about. And _that_ is easy to test. Unless you are arguing it is somehow valid to silently catch and discard `AssertionError`, `RecursionError`, `SyntaxError` or `MemoryError` in general purpose code such as this exemple?

Comment: @spectras: I'm not saying it's "valid" in the sense of being the intended behaviour, I'm saying that it might be less bad than leaving some undocumented error condition unhandled, that if it *was* documented I *would* want to handle.

Comment: That said, if you're catching an exception and not logging it, then of course when things go wrong, you're not going to know why unless it's well documented. If it's a `SyntaxError` that's really bad. If it's some undocumented circumstance that *isn't* the specific error condition you know about, but does throw the same type of exception, that might also be bad, depending what you'd have done in that case if you had known.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your cells into a list, or better, get column/row from nested `for i in xrange()` loops so that you can write one line of code to perform on all of them.

```
for r in xrange(0, 10):
    for c in xrange(0, 10):
        try:
            sheet(row=r, column=c).value = getData()
        except BadDataException:
            sheet(row=r, column=c).value = 'NA'
```

But as others have mentioned, if you can change getData, have it return the default (or None) instead of raising an Exception. If you can't change getData, check the documentation to see if it has a `default` option of some kind, like many Python objects (e.g., dictionaries with `.get()`)

*UPDATE*: Or, see Zakhar's answer to wrap getData if you can't change it yourself.